# In Azure Devops is there a way to Get Sources from multiple Repos for a single Build Definition?

Tags: git, azure, build, azure-devops, continuous-integration

During my build process, I am trying to create 2 artifacts.

One artifact for pipeline-related scripts and code, and another for the Release product.

I am trying to set this up in a way that the pipeline-related scripts and code are centrally managed in a separate repository and then imported into each production build pipeline upon execution. I have been able to import the code from External Git, but then I hit a snag...

The trouble that I'm running into is that when I am creating the Build Definition and arrive at the Get Sources step, I seem to only be able to pick a single source for the Build Definition... instead of being able to pick (for example) both TFS Git for one source and External Git for a second source.

[image: Azure Devops Get Sources]

Has anyone been able to figure out a method to pull code into a build process from multiple repositories?

Or does anyone have another suggestion on how to accomplish what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Have you considered submodules?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of *2020. April* this issue seems to have been solved by Azure itself.

From the page that instructs [how to build a repo](https://learn.microsoft.com/hu-hu/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/azure-repos-git?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) you can navigate to the [multi-repo checkout](https://learn.microsoft.com/hu-hu/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/multi-repo-checkout?view=azure-devops) instructions, which seems to answer your question in detail.

Answer (score 6):

In the "Get sources" phase you can't choose 2 repositories, as workaround, in the beginning of the build you can add a Command Line task or a PowerShell task that clone the second repo into `s` folder on the agent.

[image]

Comment: any tricks to loging in that is not a plain text password? 
fatal: could not read Password for 'https://***@bitbucket.org': terminal prompts disabled

Comment: @Marcom Try with PAT (Personal Access Token)

Answer (score 3):

**NO** , As of now there is no way to get from multiple repositories in Get sources step. And there has an user voice Allow **[`TFS build to depend on multiple repositories`](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services/suggestions/11592954-allow-tfs-build-to-depend-on-multiple-repositories)** which suggests similar feature, you can vote up.