# TFS Build with multiple repos with .gitmodules file is not working

Tags: git, tfs

I have an issue with TFS git while fetch contents from a repo.

Create a build pipeline for **repo1** and I want to fetch the contents of **repo2**, so in the build pipeline of repo1 added, `.gitmodules` files with below line

```
git submodule add http://mytfs:8080/tfs/collection/project/_git/repo
```

and running repo1 build with option `checkout git modules` but it only gets sources of repo1 but not repo2. How can I get contents of other repo?

Tried this https://www.benday.com/2016/11/04/one-tfs-build-multiple-git-repositories-with-submodules/ but it was no help.

Comment: Do you want only yo get the repo2 in the build? if yes, why you can just do git clone to this repo, you don't need submodule

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk I need to fetch multiple repos

Comment: So check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55712353/in-azure-devops-is-there-a-way-to-get-sources-from-multiple-repos-for-a-single-b/55713790#55713790

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure you create submodules follow [official tutorial](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules) from git.

The build pipeline will check out your Git submodules as long as they are:

- **Unauthenticated:** A public, unauthenticated repo with no credentials
  required to clone or fetch.
- **Authenticated:** **Contained in the same project**, GitHub organization, or Bitbucket Cloud account as the Git repo specified
  above.

  Added by using a URL relative to the main repository. For example,
  this one would be checked out: `git submodule add /../../submodule.git
  mymodule` This one would not be checked out: `git submodule add
  https://dev.azure.com/fabrikamfiber/_git/ConsoleApp mymodule`

Make sure that you have registered your submodules using HTTPS and not using SSH.

**The same credentials that are used by the agent to get the sources from the main repository are also used to get the sources for submodules.**

If your main repository and submodules are in an Azure Repos Git repository in your Azure DevOps project, then you can select the account used to access the sources. On the Options tab, on the Build job authorization scope menu, select either:

- Project collection to use the Project Collection Build service
  account
- Current project to use the Project Build Service account.

Make sure that whichever account you use has access to both the main repository as well as the submodules.
If your main repository and submodules are in the same GitHub organization, then the token stored in the GitHub service connection is used to access the sources.

Comment: To describe more - On TFS 2015
1 ) I have got “Test2” repo with .gitmodules file mapping to “Test1” repo. 
 2) git submodule add https://tfs.test.com:8080/tfs/gh-encore/ASP.Encore-SSP/_git/Test1  3) In TFS Build – pointing to Test2 , I checked the option – “checkout sub modules” 4) On the target server I dont see file contents of repo- Test1